# Event Receiver for lookup column value added should be updated in another column in same Sharepoint list

Tags: event-receiver

I am having the list named "XXX". In that list i have two columns named Status, which is the choice column and StatusLookup, which is lookup column. The both column should have the same choices values namely Open, Pending Approval, Cancelled. If add new item in sharepoint list, if i choose "Open" in Status column it should be automatically updated in StatusLookup column without any manual entry.

I need to know whether there is any way to update the StatusLookup column by choosing the value in Status column in Sharepoint list by using Event Receivers?

Can you please reply me as soon as possible?

Thanks,
Sugu.....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is late but I think instead of a lookup column you want the second column to be a computed column.  Then you want to make the formula be "=[choiceColumn]".  The computed columns should then always automatically update to the value in the choice column.

Supposedly you can then create a lookup column on the computed column from another list but that didn't work for me (computed column wasn't availalbe for a lookup column) which is how I ultimately found this post.  Let me know if you solved your problem.

-Rob